# Как получить "чистый" MP3 из файла?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

...или как удалить всю ненужную информацию из mp3-файла?
Нужно конвертировать файлы так, чтобы в них был "чистый" CBR поток MP3-фреймов, без тегов, без Xing и без Info.

Пробовал так:

```
# ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -vn -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -map_metadata -1 out.mp3
```

пробовал после этого выполнять

```
# id3v2 -D out.mp3
```

всё равно получается файл с Xing-заголовками!

Comment: Оказалось, эта инфа хранится как фрейм и для ее удаления достаточно сделать отступ от начала ( -ss ) и от конца ( -t ); для отступа от конца, пришлось предварительно вычислять продолжительность. Вроде, пашет.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Эффективного решения не нашел. Данный вопрос родился из задачи предварительного конвертирования файла для трансляции на icecast-сервер из php-скрипта. Перед началом отправки пропускаю первые полкилобайта, затем ищу "\xFF\xFB" - синхробайты и начинаю отправку с них. Имея в БД значения длительности композиции и засекая время начала трансляции, перед "окончанием" тоже делаю отступ и завершаю отправку данных за пару секунд до окончания композиции. Вроде, работает, но иногда (редко) плеер зависает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Да, сам вижу сколько лет вопросу, однако я на него попал из поиска.</strike>
Надо добавить параметр "-write_xing 0", т.е. для мп3 целиком строка примерно такая должна получаться:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%_source_%" -codec:a copy -map_metadata -1 -id3v2_version 0 -write_xing 0 "%_target_%"
```

Если чуть универсальнее и не только для мп3, то можно в начале задублировать "-vn" указав что поток точно без видео, а в конце перед именем выходного файла вставить "-bitexact", это уберёт из RIFF заголовка блок с LIST-INFO.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%_source_%" -vn -codec:a copy -map_metadata -1 -id3v2_version 0 -write_xing 0 -bitexact "%_target_%"
```

Это не затронет само содержимое, и не перекодирует, но надо понимать что далеко не всё сможет проиграть файл и отобразить данные о нём. Чтобы вернуть заголовок достаточно обработать ещё раз, но уже без "-write_xing 0", тогда ffmpeg соберёт и вставит заголовок обратно.

Только ffmpeg в таком заголовке оставляет избыточный паддинг и пустой блок с "Lavf". И от такого поведения избавиться похоже уже нельзя, т.к. проблема с лишним паддингом у ffmpeg со всеми форматами, даже когда в оригинальном кодере есть параметры для удаления лишней пустоты или паддинг вообще опциональный.